# Upstream Messaging Callbacks Firebase Android App

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Where can i find the implementation of callback of upstream messaging of firebase?
They have mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/upstream#handle_upstream_message_callbacks_1)
that we can set two callbacks onMessageSent or onSendError but i couldn't find the implementation there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of these methods are very simple, you can just add these methods to your extension of FirebaseMessagingService.

```
@Override
public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
    super.onMessageSent(msgId);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message sent: " + msgId);
}

@Override
public void onSendError(String msgId, Exception e) {
    super.onSendError(msgId, e);
    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending upstream message: " + e);
}
```

Note though that to optimize battery, these callbacks are batched, so you may not get the callback till a few messages are sent.